# Why does Rust borrow checker reject this code?

Tags: rust

I'm getting a Rust compile error from the borrow checker, and I don't understand why. There's probably something about lifetimes I don't fully understand.

I've boiled it down to a short code sample. In main, I want to do this:

```
fn main() {
    let codeToScan = "40 + 2";
    let mut scanner = Scanner::new(codeToScan);
    let first_token = scanner.consume_till(|c| { ! c.is_digit ()});
    println!("first token is: {}", first_token);
    // scanner.consume_till(|c| { c.is_whitespace ()}); // WHY DOES THIS LINE FAIL?
}
```

Trying to call `scanner.consume_till` a second time gives me this error:

```
example.rs:64:5: 64:12 error: cannot borrow `scanner` as mutable more than once at a time
example.rs:64     scanner.consume_till(|c| { c.is_whitespace ()}); // WHY DOES THIS LINE FAIL?
                  ^~~~~~~
example.rs:62:23: 62:30 note: previous borrow of `scanner` occurs here; the mutable borrow prevents subsequent moves, borrows, or modification of `scanner` until the borrow ends
example.rs:62     let first_token = scanner.consume_till(|c| { ! c.is_digit ()});
                                    ^~~~~~~
example.rs:65:2: 65:2 note: previous borrow ends here
example.rs:59 fn main() {
...
example.rs:65 }
```

Basically, I've made something like my own iterator, and the equivalent to the "next" method takes `&mut self`. Because of that, I can't use the method more than once in the same scope.

However, the Rust std library has an iterator which *can* be used more than once in the same scope, and it also takes a `&mut self` parameter.

```
let test = "this is a string";
let mut iterator = test.chars();
iterator.next();
iterator.next(); // This is PERFECTLY LEGAL
```

So why does the Rust std library code compile, but mine doesn't? (I'm sure the lifetime annotations are at the root of it, but my understanding of lifetimes doesn't lead to me expecting a problem).

Here's my full code (only 60 lines, shortened for this question):

```
 use std::str::{Chars};
use std::iter::{Enumerate};

#[deriving(Show)]
struct ConsumeResult<'lt> {
     value: &'lt str,
     startIndex: uint,
     endIndex: uint,
}

struct Scanner<'lt> {
    code: &'lt str,
    char_iterator: Enumerate<Chars<'lt>>,
    isEof: bool,
}

impl<'lt> Scanner<'lt> {
    fn new<'lt>(code: &'lt str) -> Scanner<'lt> {
        Scanner{code: code, char_iterator: code.chars().enumerate(), isEof: false}
    }

    fn assert_not_eof<'lt>(&'lt self) {
        if self.isEof {fail!("Scanner is at EOF."); }
    }

    fn next(&mut self) -> Option<(uint, char)> {
        self.assert_not_eof();
        let result = self.char_iterator.next();
        if result == None { self.isEof = true; }
        return result;
    }

    fn consume_till<'lt>(&'lt mut self, quit: |char| -> bool) -> ConsumeResult<'lt> {
        self.assert_not_eof();
        let mut startIndex: Option<uint> = None;
        let mut endIndex: Option<uint> = None;

        loop {
            let should_quit = match self.next() {
                None => {
                    endIndex = Some(endIndex.unwrap() + 1);
                    true
                },
                Some((i, ch)) => {
                    if startIndex == None { startIndex = Some(i);}
                    endIndex = Some(i);
                    quit (ch)
                }
            };

            if should_quit {
                return ConsumeResult{ value: self.code.slice(startIndex.unwrap(), endIndex.unwrap()),
                                      startIndex:startIndex.unwrap(), endIndex: endIndex.unwrap() };
            }
        }
    }
}

fn main() {
    let codeToScan = "40 + 2";
    let mut scanner = Scanner::new(codeToScan);
    let first_token = scanner.consume_till(|c| { ! c.is_digit ()});
    println!("first token is: {}", first_token);
    // scanner.consume_till(|c| { c.is_whitespace ()}); // WHY DOES THIS LINE FAIL?
}
```

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Here's a simpler example of the same thing:

```
struct Scanner<'a> {
    s: &'a str
}

impl<'a> Scanner<'a> {
    fn step_by_3_bytes<'a>(&'a mut self) -> &'a str {
        let return_value = self.s.slice_to(3);
        self.s = self.s.slice_from(3);
        return_value
    }
}

fn main() {
    let mut scan = Scanner { s: "123456" };

    let a = scan.step_by_3_bytes();
    println!("{}", a);

    let b = scan.step_by_3_bytes();
    println!("{}", b);
}
```

If [you compile that](http://play.rust-lang.org/?run=1&code=struct%20Scanner%3C%27a%3E%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20s%3A%20%26%27a%20str%0A%7D%0A%0Aimpl%3C%27a%3E%20Scanner%3C%27a%3E%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20fn%20step_by_3_bytes%3C%27a%3E%28%26%27a%20mut%20self%29%20-%3E%20%26%27a%20str%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20let%20return_value%20%3D%20self.s.slice_to%283%29%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20self.s%20%3D%20self.s.slice_from%283%29%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return_value%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%7D%0A%0Afn%20main%28%29%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20let%20mut%20scan%20%3D%20Scanner%20%7B%20s%3A%20%22123456%22%20%7D%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%0A%20%20%20%20let%20a%20%3D%20scan.step_by_3_bytes%28%29%3B%0A%20%20%20%20println!%28%22%7B%7D%22%2C%20a%29%3B%0A%0A%20%20%20%20let%20b%20%3D%20scan.step_by_3_bytes%28%29%3B%0A%20%20%20%20println!%28%22%7B%7D%22%2C%20b%29%3B%0A%7D), you get errors like the code in the question:

```
<anon>:19:13: 19:17 error: cannot borrow `scan` as mutable more than once at a time
<anon>:19     let b = scan.step_by_3_bytes();
                      ^~~~
<anon>:16:13: 16:17 note: previous borrow of `scan` occurs here; the mutable borrow prevents subsequent moves, borrows, or modification of `scan` until the borrow ends
<anon>:16     let a = scan.step_by_3_bytes();
                      ^~~~
<anon>:21:2: 21:2 note: previous borrow ends here
<anon>:13 fn main() {
...
<anon>:21 }
          ^
```

Now, the first thing to do is to avoid shadowing lifetimes: that is, this code has two lifetimes called `'a` and all the `'a`s in `step_by_3_bytes` refer to the `'a` declare there, none of them actually refer to the `'a` in `Scanner<'a>`. I'll rename the inner one to make it crystal clear what is going on

```
impl<'a> Scanner<'a> {
    fn step_by_3_bytes<'b>(&'b mut self) -> &'b str {
```

The problem here is the `'b` is connecting the `self` object with the `str` return value. The compiler has to assume that calling `step_by_3_bytes` can make arbitrary modifications, including invalidating previous return values, when looking at the definition of `step_by_3_bytes` from the outside (which is how the compiler works, type checking is purely based on type signatures of things that are called, no introspect). That is, it *could* be defined like

```
struct Scanner<'a> {
    s: &'a str,
    other: String,
    count: uint
}

impl<'a> Scanner<'a> {
    fn step_by_3_bytes<'b>(&'b mut self) -> &'b str {
        self.other.push_str(self.s);
        // return a reference into data we own
        self.other.as_slice()
    }
}
```

Now, each call to `step_by_3_bytes` starts modifying the object that previous return values came from. E.g. it could cause the `String` to reallocate and thus move in memory, leaving any other `&str` return values as dangling pointers. Rust protects against this by tracking these references and disallowing mutation if it could cause such catastrophic events. Going back to our actual code: the compiler is type checking `main` just by looking at the type signature of `step_by_3_bytes`/`consume_till` and so it can only assume the worst case scenario (i.e. the example I just gave).

---

## How do we solve this?

Let's take a step back: as if we're just starting out and don't know which lifetimes we want for the return values, so we'll just leave them anonymous (not actually valid Rust):

```
impl<'a> Scanner<'a> {
    fn step_by_3_bytes<'b>(&'_ mut self) -> &'_ str {
```

Now, we get to ask the fun question: which lifetimes do we want where?

It's almost always best to annotate the longest valid lifetimes, and we know our return value lives for `'a` (since it comes straight of the `s` field, and that `&str` is valid for `'a`). That is,

```
impl<'a> Scanner<'a> {
    fn step_by_3_bytes<'b>(&'_ mut self) -> &'a str {
```

For the other `'_`, we don't actually care: as API designers, we don't have any particular desire or need to connect the `self` borrow with any other references (unlike the return value, where we wanted/needed to express which memory it came from). So, we might as well leave it off

```
impl<'a> Scanner<'a> {
    fn step_by_3_bytes<'b>(&mut self) -> &'a str {
```

The `'b` is unused, so it can be killed, leaving us with

```
impl<'a> Scanner<'a> {
    fn step_by_3_bytes(&mut self) -> &'a str {
```

This expresses that `Scanner` is referring to some memory that is valid for at least `'a`, and then returning references into just that memory. The `self` object is essentially just a proxy for manipulating those views: once you have the reference it returns, you can discard the `Scanner` (or call more methods).

In summary, [the full, working code](http://play.rust-lang.org/?run=1&code=struct%20Scanner%3C%27a%3E%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20s%3A%20%26%27a%20str%0A%7D%0A%0Aimpl%3C%27a%3E%20Scanner%3C%27a%3E%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20fn%20step_by_3_bytes%28%26mut%20self%29%20-%3E%20%26%27a%20str%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20let%20return_value%20%3D%20self.s.slice_to%283%29%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20self.s%20%3D%20self.s.slice_from%283%29%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return_value%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%7D%0A%0Afn%20main%28%29%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20let%20mut%20scan%20%3D%20Scanner%20%7B%20s%3A%20%22123456%22%20%7D%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%0A%20%20%20%20let%20a%20%3D%20scan.step_by_3_bytes%28%29%3B%0A%20%20%20%20println!%28%22%7B%7D%22%2C%20a%29%3B%0A%0A%20%20%20%20let%20b%20%3D%20scan.step_by_3_bytes%28%29%3B%0A%20%20%20%20println!%28%22%7B%7D%22%2C%20b%29%3B%0A%7D) is

```
struct Scanner<'a> {
    s: &'a str
}

impl<'a> Scanner<'a> {
    fn step_by_3_bytes(&mut self) -> &'a str {
        let return_value = self.s.slice_to(3);
        self.s = self.s.slice_from(3);
        return_value
    }
}

fn main() {
    let mut scan = Scanner { s: "123456" };

    let a = scan.step_by_3_bytes();
    println!("{}", a);

    let b = scan.step_by_3_bytes();
    println!("{}", b);
}
```

[Applying this change](http://play.rust-lang.org/?run=1&code=use%20std%3A%3Astr%3A%3A%7BChars%7D%3B%0Ause%20std%3A%3Aiter%3A%3A%7BEnumerate%7D%3B%0A%0A%23[deriving%28Show%29]%0Astruct%20ConsumeResult%3C%27lt%3E%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20value%3A%20%26%27lt%20str%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20startIndex%3A%20uint%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20endIndex%3A%20uint%2C%0A%7D%0A%0Astruct%20Scanner%3C%27lt%3E%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20code%3A%20%26%27lt%20str%2C%0A%20%20%20%20char_iterator%3A%20Enumerate%3CChars%3C%27lt%3E%3E%2C%0A%20%20%20%20isEof%3A%20bool%2C%0A%7D%0A%0Aimpl%3C%27lt%3E%20Scanner%3C%27lt%3E%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20fn%20new%3C%27lt%3E%28code%3A%20%26%27lt%20str%29%20-%3E%20Scanner%3C%27lt%3E%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20Scanner%7Bcode%3A%20code%2C%20char_iterator%3A%20code.chars%28%29.enumerate%28%29%2C%20isEof%3A%20false%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%0A%20%20%20%20fn%20assert_not_eof%3C%27lt%3E%28%26%27lt%20self%29%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20if%20self.isEof%20%7Bfail!%28%22Scanner%20is%20at%20EOF.%22%29%3B%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%0A%20%20%20%20fn%20next%28%26mut%20self%29%20-%3E%20Option%3C%28uint%2C%20char%29%3E%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20self.assert_not_eof%28%29%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20let%20result%20%3D%20self.char_iterator.next%28%29%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20if%20result%20%3D%3D%20None%20%7B%20self.isEof%20%3D%20true%3B%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20result%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%0A%20%20%20%20fn%20consume_till%28%26mut%20self%2C%20quit%3A%20%7Cchar%7C%20-%3E%20bool%29%20-%3E%20ConsumeResult%3C%27lt%3E%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20self.assert_not_eof%28%29%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20let%20mut%20startIndex%3A%20Option%3Cuint%3E%20%3D%20None%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20let%20mut%20endIndex%3A%20Option%3Cuint%3E%20%3D%20None%3B%0A%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20loop%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20let%20should_quit%20%3D%20match%20self.next%28%29%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20None%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20endIndex%20%3D%20Some%28endIndex.unwrap%28%29%20%2B%201%29%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20true%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20Some%28%28i%2C%20ch%29%29%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20if%20startIndex%20%3D%3D%20None%20%7B%20startIndex%20%3D%20Some%28i%29%3B%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20endIndex%20%3D%20Some%28i%29%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20quit%20%28ch%29%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%3B%0A%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20if%20should_quit%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20ConsumeResult%7B%20value%3A%20self.code.slice%28startIndex.unwrap%28%29%2C%20endIndex.unwrap%28%29%29%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20startIndex%3AstartIndex.unwrap%28%29%2C%20endIndex%3A%20endIndex.unwrap%28%29%20%7D%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%7D%0A%0Afn%20main%28%29%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20let%20codeToScan%20%3D%20%2240%20%2B%202%22%3B%0A%20%20%20%20let%20mut%20scanner%20%3D%20Scanner%3A%3Anew%28codeToScan%29%3B%0A%20%20%20%20let%20first_token%20%3D%20scanner.consume_till%28%7Cc%7C%20%7B%20!%20c.is_digit%20%28%29%7D%29%3B%0A%20%20%20%20println!%28%22first%20token%20is%3A%20%7B%7D%22%2C%20first_token%29%3B%0A%20%20%20%20let%20second_token%20%3D%20scanner.consume_till%28%7Cc%7C%20%7B%20c.is_whitespace%20%28%29%7D%29%3B%20%0A%20%20%20%20println!%28%22second%20token%20is%3A%20%7B%7D%22%2C%20second_token%29%3B%0A%7D) to your code is simply adjusting the definition of `consume_till`.

```
fn consume_till(&mut self, quit: |char| -> bool) -> ConsumeResult<'lt> {
```

---

> So why does the Rust std library code compile, but mine doesn't? (I'm sure the lifetime annotations are at the root of it, but my understanding of lifetimes doesn't lead to me expecting a problem).

There's a slight (but not huge) difference here: `Chars` is just returning a `char`, i.e. no lifetimes in the return value. The `next` method (essentially) has signature:

```
impl<'a> Chars<'a> {
    fn next(&mut self) -> Option<char> {
```

(It's actually in an `Iterator` trait `impl`, but that's not important.)

The situation you have here is similar to writing

```
impl<'a> Chars<'a> {
    fn next(&'a mut self) -> Option<char> {
```

(Similar in terms of "incorrect linking of lifetimes", the details differ.)

Comment: Fantastic! I have it working, and more importantly, I've learned a ton. Thank you and @ChrisMorgan. Is there a resource anywhere that explains these characteristics of lifetimes? (see next comment)

Comment: For example, I didn't know that: (1) lifetimes could shadow other lifetimes; (2) a fn like consume_till could reference a lifetime in its return type that was not part of the fn's type (in < and > right after the fn name); (3) that a struct lifetime was "global" in the sense that other code could refer to it separately; (4) that a lifetime annotation on a `&self` or `&mut self` parameter could actually make that borrow live longer; (5) what even determines the length of the borrow for a `&self` or `&mut self` parameter in the first place? *Is delving into compiler src the only way as of now?*

Comment: @SteveKlabnik, my previous comment might give you some ideas of good topics to cover for Rust learners as you flesh out the Rust documentation.

Comment: Maybe learning a bit of Cyclone would clear up some of this? I know some of the concepts were borrowed from there.

Comment: (1) is (a little) covered by [#11658](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/11658), (2) and (3) are just "type variable scoping", i.e. lifetimes/type variables are visible inside the `fn`s and `impl`s they are declared on. (4) and (5): it's "making" the borrow live longer because it's stating that the return value is pinned to it, i.e. `self` is borrowed for the scope (or nearest enclosing statement, if it's not immediately assigned to a variable) in which the borrow was created (it's easier to think of this as "borrow lasts for as long as the return value is held").

Comment: @CharlieFlowers thanks. The Lifetimes guide is early on my list of things to re-do.

Comment: I don't think looking at the compiler source to derive the algorithm is a good idea, nor do I think learning Cyclone is a good way to approach this, I would imagine there is even fewer learning resources for Cyclone than for Rust. IMO the system in Rust is fairly simple, it just takes a bit of time/practice to 'click' (I know it took me a while to get the hang of it), but it shouldn't be regarded as some sort of complicated beast.

Comment: So @dbaupp, is this statement accurate: "A `&self` or `&mut self` borrow's scope is only for the immediately encolsing statement, unless you either (1) assign it to a variable, or (2) pin the return value to its lifetime."?

Comment: @SteveKlabnik and dbaupp, I think this statement from the lifetimes guide is inaccurate. Do you all agree? "In general, it is only possible to return references if they are derived from a parameter to the procedure. In that case, the pointer result will always have the same lifetime as one of the parameters; named lifetimes indicate which parameter that is." (Inaccurate, because the lifetime of the returned reference might be derived from the impl of the struct the fn is inside).

Comment: @CharlieFlowers "A &self or &mut self borrow's scope is only for the immediately enclosing statement, unless lifetimes force it to be longer." E.g. `fn foo(&mut self) -> uint` can be assigned to variables as much as you like, without extending the borrow because the (implicit, anonymous) lifetime on `self` is not connected to anything, so the compiler doesn't need hold the borrow. (That is, if you are holding data with lifetime `'a`, everything else with lifetime `'a` has to be kept in a valid state, i.e. you can't touch an `&'a mut self`, because things could change.)

Comment: @CharlieFlowers, the first half of the statement *is* (mostly) accurate, since the reference is derived from `self` (i.e. it's saying that you can't return a reference to a local variable). The second half isn't as accurate, as you say. (The first half ignores the fact you can return a `&'static Foo`, via `static X: Foo = ...; &X`.)

Comment: Sorry, if there's no connection between the return value and the `&` reference, then the borrow is just that expression: `x.takes_mut_self() == x.takes_mut_self()` is fine (if the function returns, e.g., `uint`) despite "borrowing" `x` mutably twice in a single statement. If there are references, the borrow is artificially extended to the statement (because the alternative is very annoying to use: a lot of temporary variables).

Comment: After digesting this, I see now that what felt like a big mystery to me was mostly just discovering the scoping rules for lifetimes. I don't see the lifetimes guide (or any other doc) covering struct lifetimes or impl lifetimes at all, so I only knew such a thing was possible from compiler error messages, and they didn't give me the detail I needed. Of course, we all know doc is needed, and good stuff is underway. So I look forward to the update @steveklabnik will produce.  Thanks all of you again.

Comment: Yup, it'll get there.

Comment: Outstanding answer!

Answer (score 5):

Let’s look at `consume_till`.

It takes `&'lt mut self` and returns `ConsumeResult<'lt>`. This means that the lifetime `'lt`, the duration of the borrow of the input parameter `self`, will be that of the output parameter, the return value.

Expressed another way, after calling `consume_till`, you cannot use `self` again until its result is out of scope.

That result is placed into `first_token`, and `first_token` is still in scope in your last line.

In order to get around this, you must cause `first_token` to pass out of scope; the insertion of a new block around it will do this:

```
fn main() {
    let code_to_scan = "40 + 2";
    let mut scanner = Scanner::new(code_to_scan);
    {
        let first_token = scanner.consume_till(|c| !c.is_digit());
        println!("first token is: {}", first_token);
    }
    scanner.consume_till(|c| c.is_whitespace());
}
```

All this does stand to reason: while you have a reference to something inside the `Scanner`, it is not safe to let you modify it, lest that reference be invalidated. This is the memory safety that Rust provides.

Comment: I'm not so sure this is correct, @ChrisMorgan. The reason I say that is that your response would mean that the lifetime annotations actually extended the life of the `&mut self` borrow, but I thought the lifetime annotations were merely an assertion to the compiler about the lifetime of the *return* value. If the `&mut self` borrow lives for the whole scope of main, then why can the Rust chars() iterator be called twice in a row (it also takes `&mut self`)? I need a deeper understanding of what's actually happening here, or else I'm just guessing in the dark. Thanks.

Comment: [`chars()` takes `&self`, not `&mut self`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/str/primitive.str.html#method.chars), and having multiple immutable borrows alive at the same time is fine—it’s just mutable borrows that you can’t do that for. Does that clear it up, or do you want me to explain further?

Comment: Here's the code from github at https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/blob/master/src/libcore/str.rs `impl<'a> Iterator<char> for Chars<'a> {
    #[inline]
    fn next(&mut self) -> Option<char> {`

Comment: And btw, @ChrisMorgan, please don't get me wrong. I greatly appreciate any help you offer. I'm sold on the promise of Rust, and I'm very eager for some deep understanding. The lifetimes guide is a good start, but it's not deep enough to give me all the help I need. If you or anyone can help, I appreciate it tremendously.

Comment: `.chars()` returns a `Chars` object which contains an immutable reference to the original string slice. Its `next()` method takes a mutable reference *to the `Chars` object*, but that does *not* give mutable access to the string, because it only has an immutable slice on *it*. Thus, calling `next` can modify the `Chars` object, but not the underlying `&str`. What this means in practice is that it will update its own understanding of where it is in the string—but that does not mean that it modifies the string, nor is it able to.

Comment: But isn't that the same thing that I am doing above? None of my code ever plans to change the "code" string, so my intent was to have nothing but immutable refs to it. The only reason I take `&mut self` is because rustc insists on it because I update my iterator position within the string.

Comment: The iterator implementation for `Chars` returns something that is not tied to `self`, but rather to the original, immutable, string. Thus, although it takes `&mut self`, that mutable reference is only taken for the duration of the method call. Your `consume_till` returns something which is tied to `self`, and so the `&mut self` reference must last until the `ConsumeResult` passes out of scope.

Comment: @CharlieFlowers it may just work if you remove the `<'lt>` declaration and the `'lt` from `&mut self` (both on `consume_till`).

Comment: Oh yes, I hadn’t noticed the lifetime shadowing there. That’ll teach me not to pay attention to the full code… @dbaupp: want to provide a better answer, or shall we update mine?